# chkrootkit weird output DEBIAN 9

Tags: rootkits, debian

I recently had this in the *chkrootkit* output comparison :

```
+! 7:0|          255 0:0|242:0|243:0|245:0|253:1|254:1|7:0| -stringPrefs 3:7;release|174:3;1.0|191:332;  ¼½¾ǃː??։֊׃״܁܂܃܄ᅟᅠ᜵           ???‐’․‧??????? ‹›⁁⁄⁒ ⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚?⅜⅝⅞⅟∕∶⎮╱⧶⧸⫻⫽⿰⿱⿲⿳⿴⿵⿶⿷⿸⿹
```

This happened since I updated to *DEBIAN 9*, so I guess it's a *debian* stuff.

Any advices would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Possible bug, check what's in `/var/log/chkrootkit`, or just go and purge `apt-get purge chkrootkit` or try to reinstall: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall chkrootkit`

Comment: It's an output from *log.today*, I use automated mailing and *chkrootkit* compare everyday log of yesterday (*log.expected*) with the new one (*log.today*). This output doesn't happen everytime but appears on both computers running *DEBIAN 9*.